# Live USB not booting in Lenovo IdeaPad Z570

Tags: boot, live-usb, boot-failure, lenovo

I have a Lenovo IdeaPad Z570 with most recent BIOS version.
I created a USB stick to book Ubuntu from but the IdeaPad does not list/show the stick when I want to select it for booting?

I did try all USB sockets on the machine as well as multiple sequences in the BIOS for booting.

How can I get the notebook to boot from the USB?

PS: the USB stick works fine on a Lenovo Thinkpad T410 and I did update the BIOS as suggested [in this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/75747/lenovo-ideapad-z570-fails-to-boot).

Comment: When you boot, strike the keystroke to get into your BIOS, then look for a boot device order setting, and be sure to enable USB

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem like you about a month ago when I purchased this laptop. There's a problem with bios settings or better speaking with the graphic card.

In bios, "Graphic Device" must not be set "Optimus" (Intel VGA+ nVidia VGA) but "UMA only". That way it loads. Otherwise, not.

Answer (score 1):

I did try now another USB stick which stragely worked.
Else I would have tried a SD card...